# Recursive Joins with Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am using LinqToDB to help query a SQLite Database, however, I am having an issue where I need to do a join in a collection of joins. Here is what I have so far.

```
var craftList = from c in db.GetTable<Craft>()
    join cP in db.GetTable<CraftProduct>() on c.ID equals cP.CraftID into cPS
    join cM in db.GetTable<CraftMaterial>() on c.ID equals cM.CraftID into cMS
    select new
    {
        Craft = c,
        CraftProducts = cPS,
        CraftMaterials = cMS
    };
```

I need to do add to the groups cPS & cMS and have each element join with another table. Here is an example query that kind of shows you what needs to be done with the elements in cMS.

```
var materialList = from cM in db.GetTable<CraftMaterial>()
    join i in db.GetTable<Item>() on cM.ItemID equals i.ID
    select CraftMaterial.Build(cM, i);
```

Comment: you probably don't need to do joins at all. you can probably do things like `var c = db.GetTable<Craft>().First(); var prod = c.CraftProducts.First();`

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work at all since `Craft` does not have a `CraftProducts` property. `CraftProducts` is a property of an anonymous type that I am using to organize everything.

Comment: so you're saying that you don't have a foreign key set up to link the `CraftID` to the `Craft.ID`. if you add a foreign key, it will create a `CraftProducts` property to `Craft`, allowing you to avoid writing explicit joins like this all the time.

Comment: I don't have access to modify the Schema of the SQLite database.

Comment: okay. well, either way, you haven't described what problem you're actually having.

Comment: I need all the elements in cPS and cMS to be joined, the second part of code shows an example of how one element from cMS needs to be joined with `db.GetTable<Item>()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80613/discussion-between-7h3laughingman-and-dleh).

Comment: @DLeh, I am confused on what else there is to explain. I need to go through each element in `cPS` & `cMS` and link them based on their `cM.ItemID` or `cP.ItemID` to the `ID` property from `db.GetTable<Item>()`. I even gave an example showing how such a link would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out what I needed to do after some messing around, I just needed to do multiple queries.

```
var craftList = from craft in db.GetTable<Craft>()
                join craftProduct in db.GetTable<CraftProduct>() on craft.ID equals craftProduct.CraftID into
                    craftProducts
                join craftMaterial in db.GetTable<CraftMaterial>() on craft.ID equals craftMaterial.CraftID into
                    craftMaterials
                select new
                {
                    Craft = craft,
                    CraftProducts = from craftProduct in craftProducts
                                    join item in db.GetTable<Item>() on craftProduct.ItemID equals item.ID
                                    select CraftProduct.Build(craftProduct, item),
                    CraftMaterials = from craftMaterial in craftMaterials
                                     join item in db.GetTable<Item>() on craftMaterial.ItemID equals item.ID
                                     select CraftMaterial.Build(craftMaterial, item)
                };
```